Change color of spelling mistake squiggles in Visual Studio?
As the title says.
The longer version: In my solution I have an .editorconfig file which configures spell-checking and I have enabled the spell checker. Spelling mistakes are underlined with blue squiggles. Suppose that I want them to be underlined with yellow squiggles. How do I do that? I went through the entire unstructured, unsearchable, insultingly long list of colors in the settings of visual studio ("Tools" -> "Options" -> "Environment" -> "Fonts and Colors") and I did not find anything related to "spell" or "typo".
How do I change the color of the squiggles for spelling mistakes?

Have you looked in "Tools" menu -> "Options" -> "Environment" -> "Fonts and Colors"? If there isn't an obvious one, you can go through the list with the keyboard down-arrow to see if one is the squiggly blue line.

@AndrewMorton thanks, I have used the keyboard-down-arrow-and-keep-eyes-peeled-looking-for-a-color trick before, but #AintNoBodyGotNoTimeFoDat and #IAmTooOldForThisShit.

The spelling errors are in the same category as general info messages, unfortunately. To change the color of the spelling errors, you need to change the color of all messages in Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors for Information:

This will do what you need. But as a side effect, all VS info messages will be displayed in yellow in the scroll bar:

If not unselected in the options:

The Information category contains all the messages that are displayed in the Error List under the "Messages" selection:

